# Unique hash of string words

Tags: c++, string, hash, integer, hashtable

I am writing a hash function for string words of arbitrary (maximum possible length < 26).
My original approach was to sum up the ASCII values of each letter in the words-as implemented in C++:

```
    int getKey(string value){
    int key = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    int length = value.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++){
        temp = (int)value[i];
        key = key + temp;
    }
    return key;
}
```

However, I soon realized such method will result in too many repetitions (for example, words consisting of same set of letters). So I am wondering if there a way to get a hash value representable by an C++ int that's unique to any word under the given length?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)?

Comment: A fundamental property of hash functions is that if the produced hash has `n` bits of precision, it cannot mathematically be unique for all possible sets of input greater than `n` bits. Therefore, if you need a hash function that's "unique to any word under the given length", the hash function must produce a result that's the same number of bytes long. In other words, the hash function is the same as the string to be hashed. Q.E.D.

Comment: Google "hash functions" and you will find a wealth of examples and theory to help you. If you've already done that, edit your question and discuss what you've found and why it hasn't worked for you.

Comment: Using the sum of stuff as a hash is bad since certain values have a way higher chance of being returned than others because they can be summed to in a lot of different ways. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ Quick search for "string hashing" would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider that there are about 5 bits of information in a typical text string (26 upper-case, 26 lower and some punctuation is about 64 different characters), then with 26-character strings you would need about 130 bits and a perfect hash function to avoid collisions. Either use `std::hash<>` if a rare collision is acceptable - it returns a `size_t` which is typically 64 bits - or something like `SHA256` if you want statistically unique hashes.

More technical details may be found over on [Cryptography StackExchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), perhaps.